# How can I use AlarmClock on Android 2.2?

Tags: android, alarms

I'm trying to use AlarmClock in my app, but I'm using android 2.2 and have a error message saying that Field requires API level 9 (current min is 8). 
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. Increase your `android:minSdkVersion` to 9, or
2. Don't use `AlarmClock` at all, or
3. Check `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to see if you are on `Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD` or higher, and only use `AlarmClock` on devices where this is true (then add the `TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD`) annotation to the method where you are using `AlarmClock` to get rid of the error message)

`AlarmClock` itself was only added in API Level 9, and therefore cannot be used on API Level 8 or below.